# Try to make an inner join in symfony

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, inner-join

I get the error *"QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 136 near 'idPat = :idP': Error: Class permissionRolePrl has no field or association named idPat"* 
when I try to make the following inner join:

```
select pur.id_pur from 
permission_user_role_pur pur 
inner join
permission_role_action_pra pra
on pur.id_prl = pra.id_prl
where
pur.id_usr = 33
and pra.id_pat = 'TEST';
```

To do so, I did the following:

```
public function findByAction($idUsr, $IdPat)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('pur')
                ->innerJoin('pur.idPrl', 'pra')
                ->where('pur.idUsr = :idUsr')->setParameter('idUsr', $idUsr)
                ->andWhere('pra.idPat = :idPat')->setParameter('idPat', $IdPat);

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

The table pra contain the columns: idPra (PK), idPat (str), idPrl (str)

The table pur contain the columns: idPur (PK), idUsr (int), idPrl (str)

How could I make this query?

Comment: you can use Native query for this one.

Comment: Could you give me more details??

Comment: Have you correctly mapped the relationship between `pur` and `pra` tables using YAML, PHP or Annotations ?

Comment: @AnjanaSilva most likely yes, I used the auto generation script...

Comment: @Alexandre , I see. Can you physically see such relationship do exist in the `pur` tables ORM file. ? By the way where is your `->select('p')->from('ACMETestBundle:Pur', 'p')` lines ?

Answer (score 0):

First use this into your class

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
```

After that in your function do this and change according your code

```
$sql = "SELECT p.title, p.media_type, p.description
          from post p
          inner join post_hot h on p.id = h.post_id";


$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addScalarResult('title', 'title');
$rsm->addScalarResult('media_type', 'mediatype');
$rsm->addScalarResult('description', 'description');

$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

$Ipost = $query->getResult();
```